# NodeJS - Express accept request if it is from specific URL or HOST

Tags: node.js, express, npm, cors

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors module for restricting request in NodeJS-Express App. Using below code for that.

```
app.use(
   cors({ origin: "http://localhost:4201"})
);
```

So it will accept request only from http://localhost:4201 which is working fine. **But the issue is if I paste request in browser, let say http://localhost:3000/users then it is showing the data**. How can I restrict this using CORS? Is this even possible?

Comment: `But the issue is if I paste request in browser, let say http://localhost:3000/users then it is showing the data.`  what does this mean? can you elaborate more when you say origin like www.exmaple.com then it will allow request only from that domain, but your localhost:3000 doest make sense

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var origin = req.get('origin');
```

I found the solution for my question. I will check origin using this. And I will Whitelist some URL and from there only request can be made.

Answer (score 4):

You can write middleware and check if that passes from your requirement

```
 const whitelist = ['::1', '::ffff:127.0.0.1'] // and other whitelisted origins
 const corsOptionsDelegate = (req, callback) => {
    let corsOptions;
    console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress)
    if (whitelist.indexOf(req.connection.remoteAddress) !== -1) {
       corsOptions = {
        origin: true
       } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
    callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
     } else {
       corsOptions = {
        origin: false
       } // disable CORS for this request
       callback(new ErrorResponse('Your IP address not allowed to have access to this route', 403), corsOptions);
     }
     // callback(null, corsOptions)
}

const corsHandler = () => cors(corsOptionsDelegate);
module.exports = corsHandler;
```

Answer (score 2):

In a live server scenario, you would do this:

1. Users or systems that access your Express API would have to be authenticated, that means they need to have credentials for being allowed in to the API in the form of a token or API-key or a session cookie or other, that only your API can issue. This means that if I try to access it through the browser without having credentials, I would not see anything else than at most an error message from the API (like 403 forbidden).
2. In addition you would close all incoming ports to your server and maybe even block off domain urls that aren't used, with a reverse proxy or other server access control software. You would perhaps only open the port(s) to the IP addresses you allow in (if your API is for internal use for certain employees in a company for example). This is more useful to do with NGINX or htaccess or other, than in the API itself.

Usually an API have to be accessible by anyone (at least anyone in the countries/regions you specify), so that users can sign up and use your application. Access control to the API would require that they successfully log in via the frontend application or send some credentials in another form together with the request, as mentioned in #1. A simple way to authenticate a user or browser is to ask them to include an API key in the request url when they contact your API. They would maybe send their request to `https://api.example.com/users/logon?apiKey=123klkx$j23uilk1j3l1k23j3f9ssdkjlkls#$ss_33`. Because the API can recognize that key, they will be granted access and receive a response.

As mentioned by another user the common method for checking if a request is allowed to receive data from your API is to use a middleware that checks every incoming request, extracts the token/code/cookie etc. and if it matches a user with the right access level to your API it will allow the request to continue through to the controller and receive the data as a response. The `next()` function is a built in Express method that is called to send the request along if it passes the middleware checkpoint:

This kind of middleware could typically look something like this:

```js
const authenticate = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token
  if (req.headers.cookie) {
    token = getCookieValue(req.headers.cookie, '_access_token_name')
  }
  if (token === null || token === '' || token === undefined) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse('Not authorized to access this route', 401))
  }

  // Verify token

  try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
    req.user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        id: decodedToken.id,
        deletedAt: null
      }
    })

    // Did the password change after token was issued?
    if (User.changedPassword(req.user, decodedToken.iat)) {
      token = null
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Password has been changed, please log in again.', 401))
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse('Not authorized to access this route', 401))
  }

  next()
})
```

In your router you could then do this:

```js
const { logout } = require('../controllers/auth/auth')
const { authenticate } = require('../middleware/auth')

router.use(authenticate) // Protect all routes from here on

router.get('/logout', () => { .... })
```

Comment: I am developing Angular Application which is consuming NodeJS API but I want it should give response to Angular App only that means http://localhost:4200 not on browser

Comment: Yes, I understand. But is this a realistic scenario? No other users than you would sit on localhost and use your app. If you plan on other people using your app on the web, you have to use some kind of authentication system that can take many different users and browsers, not only restrict it to one development server and one developer's browser via localhost. In real life incoming requests will come via https. I updated my answer with a code example on how you can add middleware to stop "intruders".

Answer (score 2):

As per docs you could provide a regex

```
 cors({ origin: /http://localhost:4201$/})
```

or `([a-z+]+:\/\/)+([a-z]+)+(.com)+(:4201)$` = `https://google.com:4201` for staging & prod envs.

Regex testing demo: https://regex101.com/r/iSd2jo/1

This is fine only on local enviornments. For other enviornments as the port changes, you'd have to update the pattern to capture possibilities.

https://github.com/expressjs/cors